# On select change, remove readonly property and allow user type on the input

Tags: jquery

I've got a little script that allow me to select an item from a select. When this item is listed as `Item`, it means I have rate informations about this one. When the selected item is listed an `Night`, it means I can inter the rate informations as I do not have any information on this item.

Here the JS controlling my form:

```
$('select[name="BIL_Item_Quantity"], select[name="BIL_Item_Id"], input[name="BIL_Item_Rate"]').on('change keyup', function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('div.modal-body');
    var type = parent.find('select[name="BIL_Item_Id"]').find(":selected").data('item-type');

    if(type == 'Night') {
        parent.find('input[name="BIL_Item_Rate"]').prop("readonly", false);
    }
    if(type == 'Item') {
        parent.find('input[name="BIL_Item_Rate"]').prop("readonly", true);
    }

    // Get datas
    var quantity = parent.find('select[name="BIL_Item_Quantity"]').val();
    var rate = Number.parseFloat(parent.find('select[name="BIL_Item_Id"]').find(":selected").data('item-rate')).toFixed(2);
    var taxes_id = parent.find('select[name="BIL_Item_Id"]').find(":selected").data('item-taxes');
    var taxes_amount = Number.parseFloat(parent.find('select[name="BIL_Item_Id"]').find(":selected").data('item-taxes-sum')).toFixed(3);

    // Calculs
    var total_rate = (quantity * rate).toFixed(2);

    // Display
    parent.find('input[name="BIL_Item_Rate"]').val(rate);
    parent.find('input[name="BIL_Item_Total_Rate"]').val(total_rate);
    parent.find('input[name="BIL_Item_Taxes"]').val(taxes_id);
    parent.find('input[name="BIL_Item_Type"]').val(type);
});
```

What is doesn't work is when I select `Night` from the select. I can't enter a number into the input `BIL_Item_Rate` and the multiplication is not made too.

When I start typing into the input `BIL_Item_Rate` the content is removed at each keypress.

Do you know why please ?

https://jsfiddle.net/azq028g7/

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the code, you're setting the rate based on the selected item's `data-item-rate` - regardless of which dropdown option is selected. See my code below, where I moved it into the conditional checking for the value of the `select`.

```js
$('select[name="BIL_Item_Quantity"], select[name="BIL_Item_Id"], input[name="BIL_Item_Rate"]').on('change keyup', function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('div.modal-body');
    var type = parent.find('select[name="BIL_Item_Id"]').find(":selected").data('item-type');

    if(type == 'Night') {
     parent.find('input[name="BIL_Item_Rate"]').prop("readonly", false);
      var rate = Number.parseFloat(parent.find('input[name="BIL_Item_Rate"]').val()).toFixed(2);
    }
    if(type == 'Item') {
     parent.find('input[name="BIL_Item_Rate"]').prop("readonly", true);
      var rate = Number.parseFloat(parent.find('select[name="BIL_Item_Id"]').find(":selected").data('item-rate')).toFixed(2);
    }

    // Get datas
    var quantity = parent.find('select[name="BIL_Item_Quantity"]').val();
    /* var rate moved to conditional, above */    
    var taxes_id = parent.find('select[name="BIL_Item_Id"]').find(":selected").data('item-taxes');
    var taxes_amount = Number.parseFloat(parent.find('select[name="BIL_Item_Id"]').find(":selected").data('item-taxes-sum')).toFixed(3);

    // Calculs
    var total_rate = (quantity * rate).toFixed(2);

    // Display
    parent.find('input[name="BIL_Item_Rate"]').val(rate);
    parent.find('input[name="BIL_Item_Total_Rate"]').val(total_rate);
    parent.find('input[name="BIL_Item_Taxes"]').val(taxes_id);
    parent.find('input[name="BIL_Item_Type"]').val(type);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3">Bill an item</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <select class="form-control" name="BIL_Item_Id">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="" data-item-rate="" data-item-taxes="7" data-item-taxes-sum="0" data-item-type="Night">Night</option>
                    <option value="17" data-item-rate="21.00" data-item-taxes="8,7" data-item-taxes-sum="0" data-item-type="Item">Breakfast</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3">Quantity</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <select class="form-control" name="BIL_Item_Quantity">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3">Unit rate</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="number" class="form-control col-xs-2" name="BIL_Item_Rate" required="" readonly="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3">Total</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="BIL_Item_Total_Rate" required="" readonly="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="BIL_Item_Taxes" value="">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="BIL_Item_Type" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Last thing how can I empty `BIL_Item_Rate` each time the item `Night` is selected ?

Comment: @Joe Personally, I would break out the function, into 3 separate ones - one for each form control. Then it'd be easier to control each individual action, and whenever the Item Type is changed, it would clear the respective fields.

Comment: @Joe, here's a JSFiddle I threw together, showing the points: https://jsfiddle.net/Matthew_Moore/3mnef078/26/